# NSURL not working after retrieved from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsurl, audio-recording

Having trouble storing an audio recording file address in an array and using it later.
This is how I get the URL address, convert it to a string and add it to the array.  This seems to work.

testViewController.h

```
@interface record_audio_testViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {       
NSURL *audioFile;
AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *audioFile;
```

---

testViewController.m

```
#import "record_audio_testViewController.h"
@implementation record_audio_testViewController
@synthesize audioFile

- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSMutableArray *urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    audioFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"]]];
    //  convert NSURL to NSString
    NSString *fileLoc = [audioFile absoluteString];
    [urlArray addObject: fileLoc ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlArray forKey:@"urlArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [urlArray release];
    //  Create an AVAudioSession object.
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];
    //Activate the session
    [audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];
}
```

---

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button {
    NSMutableArray *urlArray;
    urlArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"urlArray"];
    audioFile = [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:btnN] ];
    //  at this point, the URL looks exactly as created
}
```

---

```
- (IBAction)  rec_button_pressed {
    NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];        
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: audioFile settings: recordSetting error:&error ]; //  this is where it CRASHES

    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [recorder record];
}
```

When I use NSLog to look at and compare these addresses, they all look the same.  But the program throws an exception:

```
    Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 address=0x9)
```

Anyone know how to get through this situation?
Also, are there easier and/or safer ways to do this?

Comment: Where is the bad access happening? Also, are you using ARC? When you store a URL, you should actually get the bookmark data and store that, and then read the bookmark data later and create a URL out of it. Also, is the audio date really still there? The temp directory can get emptied anytime and your file may not actually be there anymore, especially if it was large.

Comment: it happens on    recorder =   Not using ARC in this project.  Not familiar with bookmark data.  Haven't actually gotten as far as finding out if my audio data is still there.  I want to record maybe 50 to 200 short audio files and access them at will.  I just don't know why the URL crashes if is looks exactly the same as earlier.

Comment: I'm assuming the  initWithURL: audioFile  is the problem.  Could be wrong.

Comment: For example, using NSLog, here are the BEFORE and AFTER values of   audioFile:    file://localhost/Users/apple/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/99B96531-3BB0-4440-ABC6-916F794244CA/tmp/3705780443938.caf
 file://localhost/Users/apple/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/99B96531-3BB0-4440-ABC6-916F794244CA/tmp/3705780443938.caf

Comment: Where is `audioFile` being stored? Is that a local variable or an instance variable? Can you edit your question to include the entire method body of the method that causes the error? It would help us help you a lot.

Comment: OK, I replaced the code I first included with larger sections of the code, but I've removed a bunch of the stuff that's irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, so since you're using managed memory, you need to take ownership when you assign audioFile. It's getting released when your button clicked method ends. I suggest using ARC, if possible, as it will minimize these issues.

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  I'll take your advice.  My buddy, NOP, just gave me the immediate fix:  audioFile = [NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:btnN] ];  should be:   audioFile = [[NSURL URLWithString: [urlArray objectAtIndex:btnN] ] retain];  That keeps me going, for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're showing could be completely irrelevant, since it isn't here that the exception is being thrown. The exception is probably due to a memory management error, and might have nothing to do with NSURL. You are just guessing about that - and you shouldn't be.

There is no memory management in your code, and since you are not using ARC, that suggests that you're unaware of your memory management responsibilities. My book explains them to you, and also explains why you should use ARC if you can:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html

Also, use the static analyzer; it will spot some of the danger signs of memory mismanagement.

Comment: Ok, no doubt, I've got a LOT to learn about responsible coding.  This is in prototype now, and I intend to start over and use ARC when I think this project is really worth doing.  Back to the issue, everything works great if I put this:   audioFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:. . . .   immediately before the:  recorder = [[ . . . line.  But, again, with NSLog, they look exactly the same.

Comment: You don't get to ignore memory management even when prototyping. Objective-C isn't that sort of language. There is no reason, so far, to think that the NSURL is anything but a red herring.

Comment: Ok, I ran ANALYZE and got this:  .../record_audio_testViewController.m:292:9: Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'recordSetting' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Comment: I did a [recordSetting release] to get rid of it.